# Web Fonts messed up on Windows 10

Tags: vue.js, webfonts

I noticed that my font with 16px size is messed up somehow only on Windows

Here it is on Google Chrome macOS

[image]

Here it is on Google Chrome Windows 10

[image]

This is main font-face css in App.vue

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "sukhumvit";
    src: url("../public/fonts/sukhumvit/sukhumvit-text-webfont.eot");
    src: url("../public/fonts/sukhumvit/sukhumvit-text-webfont.eot?#iefix")
            format("embedded-opentype"),
        url("../public/fonts/sukhumvit/sukhumvit-text-webfont.woff2")
            format("woff2"),
        url("../public/fonts/sukhumvit/sukhumvit-text-webfont.woff")
            format("woff"),
        url("../public/fonts/sukhumvit/sukhumvit-text-webfont.ttf")
            format("truetype");

    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
}

#app {
    font-family: "sukhumvit";
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

}
```

Comment: So it's just a glitch in the 'e'? Are both Chromes using the same format (woff2)? Do you still see the error at other font sizes? If you drop the woff2 file do the other formats render with the same error? If you clear your Windows Chrome cache does it go away, i.e. the file was corrupted somehow?

Comment: But chances are this needs to be a Chrome bug report and there isn't anything we can do to help you. And you'll have to send them the font file with the report.

Comment: It only messed up when size is 16px when I resize it becomes normal and by dropping the woff2 file still show the same result. I also tried to remove both woff2 and woff and the browser use ttf instead but still no change the letter e and a are still messed up

Comment: I think the problem is with the fonts itself cause I try using other fonts instead and there is no problem

Comment: this is happening to my with Open Sans, woff2, windows + chrome, Sept 30th '21
so... thumbsup if you are here on '21 xd